# How to invoke DRF has_object_permission() method with a function based view and Token auth?

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF with authentication. I have implemented both Session and Token auth. The first is used by the browsable API that I use to debug and the second is the auth that will be used by the actual client. I have the following detail view:

```py
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsTrainingOwner])  # this view is only available to authenticated users
def training_detail(request, pk, format=None):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a training. Need to be authenticated
    """
    print(request.user)
    try:
        training = Training.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Training.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = TrainingSerializer(training)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = TrainingSerializer(training, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        training.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

As you cas see I am using a custom permission:

```py
class IsTrainingOwner(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Custom permission to only allow owners of an object to see and edit it
    """

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Read permissions are allowed to any request,
        # so we'll always allow GET, HEAD or OPTIONS requests.
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            print("Object owner: ", obj.owner)
            print("Request user: ", request.user)
            return True

        # Instance must have an attribute named `owner`.
        print("Object owner: ", obj.owner)
        print("Request user: ", request.user)
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

This custom permission is being correctly called when I use the DRF browsable API, with the prints of object owner and request user being displayed in my console.

However, when I use Postman to test the Token permission, the 'has_object_permission' method is not called at all (I don't see any prints in my console) and I can modify the training of a user A when sending the token of a user B in the header.

I have read the DRF doc that talks about this and then decided to try a generic view:

```py
class TrainingDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsTrainingOwner]
    queryset = Training.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrainingSerializer
```

Using the generic view works well and the custom permission is invoked correctly.

So, my question is:
**Why does the custom permission works with the function based view version when I use the browsable API which uses session auth and I need to switch to the generic view version for the custom permission to work with POSTMAN?**

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the DRF documentation:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#object-level-permissions

> If you're writing your own views and want to enforce object level permissions, or if you override the get_object method on a generic view, then you'll need to explicitly call the .check_object_permissions(request, obj) method on the view at the point at which you've retrieved the object.

I think that in case of interacting with the API via the HTML interface, DRF is calling `check_object_permissions` while rendering the HTML form while your view isn't touching it at all.

Please try pulling the session cookie via browser dev tools and try using POSTMAN/curl to send the same request to fire `JSONRenderer` rather than `BrowsableAPIRenderer` (you can also force that by adding `?format=json` in the url).

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Snake9920. I think that you are right. The problem is that I have tried to call the check_object_permissions method in my function based view, but I have to admit that I don't know exactly how to do this. Could you please give me a hint of how to do this, given the code that I shared of my view? Thanks!

Comment: @DrSalas You simply have to call `self.check_object_permissions(self.request, training)` immediately after you retrieve the training object

Comment: You can't call `self.check_object_permissions` from a function-based view bc it is not available. So basically, you have to take the logic from your custom permission's `has_object_permission` and put it into your function-based view, right after you retrieve the object from the database. If that logic returns `False` then you raise a `PermissionDenied` exception.  Per docs: *Function-based views will need to check object permissions explicitly, raising PermissionDenied on failure.*